# FCC labeling rules - repackaged tablet

Tags: wifi, fcc, certification

I am considering taking a commercial available, FCC certified tablet (with 802.11 b/g/n) and packaging it in a plastic "clamshell" with an additional battery to prolong run time for a specialized application.

What would be the FCC requirements in such a situation since the "clamshell" will likely obscure the tablet's FCC label. Would it require a re-test and our own FCC id for the product?

Answer (score 2):

First FCC ID's are mainly for products with transmitters.  Most other products use a DoC or Declaration of Conformity - which is a pretty easy process.  In essence you need to be able to prove upon request that your product meets the requirements the FCC as placed on it.

Typically, I would say that a radiated emissions scan of the product without the clamshell and battery, and a second with both, and assuming they pass or at least are identical, kept in a file (forever) would be adequate to protect you from any issues with the FCC.

I would feel safe stating such in a manual - "This product conforms to the requirements..." or some such legalese, as stated on the FCC website.  You could add a label to the unit as well.

The main concern the FCC and all of us EMC type people have, is that your additional battery could cause an increase in radiated emissions from the unit.  You are tying a wire to the inside of a possibly noisy environment, and creating a passive antenna to radiated that energy.  That would need to be correct or incorrect somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Impromptu thoughts:

- You are not going to remove/modify the original case of the tablet, right?
- Is your secondary clamshell going to be removable?  My cell phone has an FCC label.  To see it, I have to remove the battery cover and the battery.  Many aftermarket cases (otter boxes, and such) obscure the FCC label.
- Of course, you could consider making a hole or transparent window in the clamshell where the label is.
- Often, there is a copy of the label (or equivalent information) in the manual.  Add the manual of the original tablet to your package.

Comment: No intention to make the case removable in the field (although it will be in the factory for returns/upgrades). Your cellphone analogy is a good one though